# Colspan e rendered não funcionam em SubTable

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Possuo uma DataTable com SubTable, utilizo renderizações nas columns de ambas as tabelas e colspan em algumas colunas. As tags rendered e colspan na subtable não funcionam como o esperado.

Olhem o código:

```

```
                            <p:columnGroup type="header">  
                                <p:row>  
                                    <p:column rowspan="2" colspan="3" headerText="Área Notificada" rendered="#{not empty relatoriosMB.listaObjeto1}"/>  
                                    <p:column colspan="#{relatoriosMB.countColumns}" headerText="Subclassificações" rendered="#{not empty relatoriosMB.listaObjeto1}"/>  
                                </p:row>  

                                <p:row>  
                                    <p:column headerText="JAN" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}"/> 
                                    <p:column headerText="FEV" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="MAR" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.marco}"/> 
                                    <p:column headerText="ABR" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.abril}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="MAI" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.maio}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="JUN" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.junho}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="JUL" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.julho}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="AGO" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="SET" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="OUT" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="NOV" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="DEZ" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="TOTAL" style="width:100px;text-align: center"/>
                                </p:row>  
                            </p:columnGroup>  

                            <p:subTable id="subTableDetalhe" var="detalhe" value="#{notificada.detalhe}">  
                                <f:facet name="header">  
                                    <h:outputText value="#{notificada.objeto}"/>  
                                </f:facet>  
                                <p:column colspan="3" >  
                                    <h:outputText value=" #{detalhe.objeto}"/>  
                                </p:column>  
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.janeiro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}"/>  
                                </p:column>  
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.fevereiro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}"/>  
                                </p:column>  
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.marco}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.marco}"/>  
                                </p:column>  
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.abril}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.abril}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.maio}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.maio}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.junho}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.junho}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.julho}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.julho}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.agosto}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.setembro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.outubro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.dezembro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.totalLinha}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:columnGroup type="footer">  
                                    <p:row>  
                                        <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align:right" footerText="Total Subclassificações:" />
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalJaneiro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}" />
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalFevereiro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.marco}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalMarco}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.marco}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.abril}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalAbril}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.abril}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.maio}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalMaio}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.maio}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.junho}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalJunho}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.junho}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.julho}"  
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalJulho}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.julho}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalAgosto}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalSetembro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalOutubro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalNovembro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalDezembro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}"/>
                                        <p:column footerText="#{notificada.totalFooter}"/>
                                    </p:row>  
                                </p:columnGroup>  
                            </p:subTable>  
                        </p:dataTable>
```

```

**IMPORTANTE:** Reparem que o mesmo rendered utilizado no footer e nos headers, que funcionam perfeitamente, estão declarados nas linhas de registro da subTable(onde não funcionam como o esperado).

e abaixo a imagem da tela:

[image: https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/th53NS7DQhOzzH0stW3c]

Alguma possível solução para este caso? Utilizo JSF 2.2 e primefaces 5.0

Comment: Fiz o upgrade da versão do Primefaces para 5.2, porém o problema ainda persiste. Realizei abertura de uma  [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/391) sobre este assunto